# how to move images from left to right with css3 animation?

Tags: css, css-animations

here am trying to load 3 images from left to right and then wait for 3 seconds and then again load from left to right. This process is continues for every 5 seconds. here am not getting how to load it from left to right and loaded images should be on one line only.

I mean in this example, images are moving from left to right but they are going to next line. i dont want to go for next line. they just load one by one with some gap from left to right only.

in this `[example]`[1](http://jsfiddle.net/mssjdb/DT6Xu/), values are fade in fade out. but i wanted to go for like left to right like movemet/ load images(appear) from bottom to top/ load(appear) images from top to bottom

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want items to go to the next line, then you need their aggregate widths to be less than 100% of the container.

10px + 80% + 10px + 80% + 10px + 80% > 100%

---

### Edit

To expound: The problem is that your right margin is 80%

```
50%  {margin-right: 80%;}
```

That means 80% of the page, which is too much. What you need to do is animate the left margin of the **last two** objects rather than the right margin of all three objects. The greatest left margin that you can have should be about 40%

```
50%  {margin-left: 40%;}
```

Note that you shouldn't have multiple elements with the same ID in HTML, but you can have multiple classes, so your divs should look like

```
<div class="ui-block-b subdiv">
```

Note also that you need to close your img tags with **/**

```
<img src="img/images.jpg"/>
```

Comment: You don't seem to have updated the fiddle since the question. I've added details to the answer to make it clearer